# Method does not throw in JUnit5 test case

Tags: java, log4j, tdd, junit5, assertion

I have a custom Log4j appender which is implemented as a Singleton class and expects a Layout object when the `getInstance()` method of the class is invoked. 
I wrote a JUnit5 test case to test whether an exception is thrown when a Layout object is not set. I thrown an `IllegalArgumentException` in case the layout is not set.

The code below throws an exception when executed

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("test");

        CustomAppender m = CustomAppender.getInstance();
        logger.addAppender(m);

        logger.info("test"); // Exception is thrown by this statement
    }
}
```

However, the test case below fails. In fact, no exceptions is thrown.

```
@Test
public void testException(){
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("test");

    CustomAppender m = CustomAppender.getInstance();
    logger.addAppender(m);

    assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> {
        logger.info("test");
    });
}
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT: Some more code from the `CustomAppender` class

```
private CustomAppender(Layout layout, ArrayList<LoggingEvent> list) {
    cLayout = layout;
    eventsList = list;
    discardedLogCount = 0;

    super.setLayout(cLayout);
}

// Instance with a user-defined list and a layout
public static CustomAppender getInstance(Layout layout, ArrayList<LoggingEvent> list) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        // Thread-safety
        synchronized (CustomAppender.class) {
            INSTANCE = new CustomAppender(layout, list);
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

// Instance with an empty list
public static CustomAppender getInstance(Layout layout){
    return CustomAppender.getInstance(layout, new ArrayList<>());
}

// Instance with a null layout
public static CustomAppender getInstance(ArrayList<LoggingEvent> list){
    return CustomAppender.getInstance(null, list);
}

// Default instance
public static CustomAppender getInstance(){
    return CustomAppender.getInstance(null, new ArrayList<>());
}

// Appends at most maxSize items
@Override
protected void append(LoggingEvent event) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (this.cLayout == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    if (eventsList.size() < maxSize) {
        eventsList.add(event);
    } else {
        // Remove the oldest item and add a new one
        eventsList.remove(0);
        discardedLogCount++;
        eventsList.add(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you throw an `IllegalArgumentException` from `CustomAppender.getInstance()` if a `Layout` parameter is not passed? Or do you wait until `Logger.info()` is invoked?

Comment: No. I know that is counterintuitive, but that is what is asked in the assignment. Instead, I perform a precondition check in the overloaded `append()` method, which is called when `Logger.info()` is executed. I used a debugger and verified that my precondition check (i.e. if my private layout object is null, throw an Exception) works okay but for some reason the test fails. In fact, if I comment `assertThrow()` call and only execute `logger.info()`, it just works fine.

Comment: And it throws the `Exception` as expected?

Comment: I think so, at least, when I execute the code step by step, the `throw new IllegalArgumentException()` line is executed.

Comment: If nothing is getting thrown, the problem must be down in the code that decides  _go_ or _no-go_ on throwing the `Exception`. If you add more of that code, I'll try to help.

Comment: Added some more code from the `CustomAppender` class

Comment: It doesn't fail because your test is not isolated. If you've already called `getInstance` on `CustomAppender` at least once and given it some `Layout`, you will get that instance with that layout from that point onwards. And since `INSTANCE` field is static, that behavior persists until ClassLoader garbage-collected, which for purposes of your test might as well be "forever". You should somehow explicitly create the appender you need, not rely on your test being the first to call that method.

Comment: In general, I find your approach peculiar. Why do you follow Singleton pattern, if your instance is actually parameterized with something from outside, thus not a singleton, but a caching factory of `Layout->Appender`? If you want it seen as Singleton by calling code, but still open for configuration at startup, you must split concerns, and not have `getInstance()` also initialize your singleton. Have another method, like `init(Layout, List)`, that way you can also use the `init` method in testing and even cleanup after test.

Comment: Thanks @M.Prokhorov, when I disabled other tests and run this one only, it passed. Using the singleton pattern is part of the statement, and as it appears, adds more challenges to the testing.

Comment: Singleton by itself doesn't pose any challenges to testing. It's your particular case of singleton configurable at initiation time by whoever races and comes first is what causing the problem. I consider`GetInstance` with parameter that it might ignore an anti-pattern, as I said before.